# How to get PHPExcel cell format

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am reading an excel file using PHPExcel. I want to know if there is way to know the cells format.
Eg: no.of decimal places, if % or number etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the number format mask for a cell by doing:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A1')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->getFormatCode();
```

which will return the formatting mask as a string

e.g

```
'£#,##0;-£#,##0'
```

or

```
'0.00%'
```

but PHPExcel provides no functionality to interpret this mask to show whether it is a percentage or how many decimals should be shown; you'd need to add that logic yourself; although you could possibly extract some of the logic for interpreting it from the code for the `toFormattedString()` method in `PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat`